# WCF not returning a string as expected

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I've designed this interface and implementation.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGeneral
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "Bamse")]
  String Ping(String input);
}

public class General : IGeneral
{
  public String Ping(String input)
  {
    return
      "pong @" + DateTime.Now
      + " with " + input;
  }
}
```

The WSDL file gets returned and lists the method. However, when navigating to it by the URL below, I'm getting nothing on the screen. I'm certain that I'm forgetting something but I can't figure out what.

> http: //.../general.svc/ping/hazaa

I noticed that accessing the service using C# code and the generated client yields the correct result. So, my conclusion is that I've done something less intelligent (or forgot to do something necessary) when exposing the service. Can't see what, though...

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata
          httpGetEnabled="true"
          httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>    
  <serviceHostingEnvironment 
    aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Post your config file

Comment: @iamkrillin Here you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your UriTemplate.

It should be something like this:

```
UriTemplate = "Ping/{input}"
```

And then you would access it like this:

```
http://localhost/general.svc/Ping/someinputhere
```

**EDIT**

If you want to maintain something like your current UriTemplate, you would still need to add a slug for your input parameter, like this:

```
UriTemplate = "Bamse/{input}"
```

And then again, to access the resource, the URL would be:

```
http://localhost/general.svc/Bamse/someinputhere
```

Comment: Not quite there yet. I've corrected the *UriTemplate* parameter and tried to access the method but I still get nothing on the screen. Also, I've noticed that misspelling the name gives no error, neither - I still get to stare at the white screen of nothingness... Also, I've had the default *DoWork* method and tried to throw an exception from there. When accessing it, I get the white emptiness anyway...

Comment: Yes, I do. And when I hit the service using the client it gives me the right *pong*. It's only the call from URL line in the browser that gives white nada.

Comment: Hmm... okay, how about changing the method's attribute to: [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "Bamse")]. I don't think it will necessarily make a difference, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Sorry. Tried that already. No avail... Can you confirm that **you** don't get to see anything on the screen neither? [Try here.](http://nobina.azurewebsites.net/general.svc)

Comment: I get an HTTP 400 Bad Request response when I try to GET the resource.

Comment: Weird. I get to see the usual page where you can see the link to WSDL file when I click that link... Tried FF and Cr and even IE.

Comment: I can see the service description just fine, sorry I should have been more specific. When I try to hit the Ping method I get the 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Can we take that in the chat? I'm curious how you get the error message. Also, I believe that something is wrong with my config file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54557/discussion-between-konrad-viltersten-and-brian-driscoll).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `<services>` section in your config file. If you want to expose a service you need to define the address, binding and contract for the service endpoint as in:

```
 <services>      
      <service name="Services.General">            
        <endpoint address="http://..general.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Services.IGeneral"/>        
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>      
      </service>
    </services>
```